# Нечеткий и морфологический поиск в PHP

Tags: php, поиск, нечеткий-поиск

Подскажите, какие средства есть для нечеткого и морфологического поиска в PHP? Интересует документация, библиотеки, примеры использования. Поддержка русского языка обязательна.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что [вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, есть phpMorphy, который частично решает задачу морфологического поиска в php.
Нечеткий поиск это однозначно сверхсложная задача, которую можно решить только огромным словарем, сверхмощным сервером (а лучше несколькими) и очень умным алгоритмом. И вряд ли есть библиотека, которая решит эту задачу, я бы первый встал на очередь в ее получение.:) Яндекс и Гугл это годами делали.

Comment: Да, в сторону phpMorphy и pspell я тоже смотрю. В моем случае задача не суперглобальная. Необходимо организовать нечеткий поиск (в самом простом варианте) по некоторой за раннее известной номенклатуре в каталоге.

Comment: Тогда давайте определимся, что вы понимаете под нечетким поиском в вашем случае.

Comment: Запросы типа "малоко", поиск по корню слова и пр...

Comment: В вашем случае задачу можно решить только составлением заранее предопределенных ошибочных слов и соответствий правильным. В противном случае получается общая сверхсложная задача. Она не решается простым подключением чудо-библиотеки. Требуются очень большие производственные мощности.

Comment: С помощью phpMorphy или Mystem от яндекса, приводите каталог к нормальной форме, пред поиском приводите ключ так же к нормальной форме.

Answer (score 0):

sphinx, elasticsearch?